# Is this siphon based recipe for mousse au chocolat trying to whip the cream?

Tags: chocolate, cream, mousse, whipping-siphon

The following recipe came with my new N2O siphon:

- dissolve 75g of chocolate in 275g of cream
- cool to 5 degree Celsius
- strain through sieve into siphon to make sure no undissolved pieces of chocolate get into siphon
- pressurize siphon
- shake 8-10 times

When I eat the mousse au chocolat immediately after letting it out of the siphon, it doesn't quite have the texture I expect from mousse au chocolat (my reference is a traditional recipe with eggs, whipped cream and chocolate), but it's still fluffy and nice. When I let it rest in in the fridge however, which usually gives mousse au chocolat a firmer texture without being less fluffy, it kind of deflates and reverts to it's pre-siphon state of liquid chocolate-cream mix. It actually keeps it's fluffiness worse than a vegan variant I also did with 250g of coconut milk and 100g of chocolate (which has enough fat that it becomes solid in the fridge and keeps it's fluffiness).

Is that supposed to happen like that? Isn't a whipped cream siphon supposed to, you know, whip the cream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected outcome. Foams made with a siphon are not especially stable over time.

If you are making a siphon recipe without stabilizers, you should prepare it in time for serving, not plan to store it.

Comment: Thanks. I was just surprised the recipe that came with the device didn't set, but it makes perfect sense that it doesn't. I like my mousse au chocolat with more chocolate anyway, and given enough chocolat it will set when cooled. Just need to find the right temperature to work with and probably get used to making a cup of hot chocolate with the rest of the mix that stays in the siphon.